# Problema KeyPressed JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, teclado

Eu queria disparar um evento apertando o botão F12, porém nao  estou conseguindo faze-lo disparar uma ação qualquer mesmo tendo criado ele em código.Eis um exemplo abaixo.

```
F12.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.F12)){
        System.out.println("NN");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso aconteceu porque você não definiu que tipo de evento você está tratando, isso pode ser feito assim:

```
public class ButtonTest extends Application{

private Button mybutton;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    VBox root = new VBox(5);
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    mybutton = new Button();
    mybutton.setDefaultButton(true);
    mybutton.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent t) -> {
        if(t.getCode() == KeyCode.F12){
            System.out.println("F12");
        }
        if(t.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE){
            t.consume();
        }
    });
    mybutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            System.out.println("Fired");
        }
    });

    root.getChildren().addAll(mybutton);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

Ou usando Lambdas:

```
Button mybutton = new Button();
mybutton.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent t) -> {
    if(t.getCode() == KeyCode.F12){
        System.out.println("F12");
    }
});
```

Você também pode usar esse código para consumir um evento que não quer que ocorra dessa forma:

```
if(t.getCode() == KeyCode.SPACE){
    t.consume();
}
```

Não há problema um mesmo botão ter um setOnAction e um setOnKeyPressed.

Comment: Então bro, ainda sim não esta funcionando. Eu criei o botão assim >> private Button F12 = new Button(); << e nao la no scene builder.Na verdade este botão não vai existie na tela, somente um label informando oq será aberto ao pressionar ele.Mas ele não ta funcionando.

Comment: O consume tambem nao funciona.O espaço continua fazendo a mesma coisa que o ENTER

Comment: Também não usei SceneBuilder nesse exemplo, tenta dar o instanciar no Initialize do controller.

Comment: Nao deu certo        .

Comment: Eu não uso FXML pra programar em JavaFX ... mas vou editar colocando o código inteiro pra você testar. Botões que não estão na tela ou invisíveis não disparam ações.

Comment: nao disparam? mas aí complica kkk pq deveriam disparar né. Pq não  me faz mt sentido ter aquele bolo de função e vc ter q colocar na sua janela todos esses botoes ao invés de labels informando oq eles fazem.Pelo menos a idéia era essa, só deixar um label escrito e  ao apertar o F12, abrir outra janela

Comment: Você pode por isso em um menu e colocar atalhos usando o Acelerometro

Comment: Cara, tenta adicionar o evento `onKeyPressed` no `anchorPane` e não no `button`.

Comment: Valeu Julio, deu certinho.